# DotNetNuke Explained: Basic Module Development - Settings not saved

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-settings

I'm using VS 2012 dotnetnuke template for develop a first module DNN 7 following the Chris Hammond's tutorial. I ve a  problem with settings : they are not saved, i uncomment all sections but when i update them, and i open settings module again they don t appear.

In fact i need to build a new release version then reinstall module and it's working but it's very difficult to develop something doing that

If someone have an idea ??

Thanks vey advance

Comment: Can we see the code where you save settings?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem came from the fact i forgot to uncheck Create folder for solution.

All is working fine now

Thank's to D. Gimenez

Comment: That can definitely cause problems ;)